# Can't add AUTO_INCREMENT on existing column because of foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have primary key column, which has some external foreign key references. Very usual. I forgot to add AUTO_INCREMENT for it. Now I execute

`ALTER TABLE chat.users 
CHANGE COLUMN user_id user_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;`

(PRIMARY KEY was defined separately)

it tells something about fk
`ERROR 1833: Cannot change column 'user_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_chats_users' of table 'chat.chats'`

I can't figure out why fk bother something about it's reference AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot change column used in a foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason the FK bothers about your changes is because you are trying to alter it and is used in a constraint, remember that you are able to alter the data type.

So if you want to make the change to the FK, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint) answer (remember to lock the tables before if you are making the change in a production environment).

Comment: So FK just block any altering even if it leave data type and all data the same? I did't thought it's so rude. Used "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;". Very helpful in my case. Thanx!

Comment: Exactly, that's the way to make sure you don't violate referential integrity. You're welcome!

Comment: "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0" Saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: @user3537411 Yup. I can agree with the ban if we are changing data type or data length, but adding and removing AUTO_INCREMENT shouldn't ruin the connection with other tables. It's kind of weird why we are disallowed to.

Answer (score -4):

> (PRIMARY KEY was defined separately)

If you have defined primary key on your column then I dont think there is any need to modify your column and add auto_increment to it. Primary keys are auto incremented by default.

However if you want to set the auto_increment feature on it then try like this:

```
--Drop foreign key
ALTER TABLE chat.users DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_chats_users;
--Alter your primary key
ALTER TABLE person modify user_id INT(11) not null auto_increment;
--Recreate foreign key
ALTER TABLE chat.users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_chats_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES chat.users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Primary keys are auto incremented by default? I can't see it. If I have't AUTO_INCREMENT explicity, then after "insert into users (username)
values("me")" where I expect user_id to be generated incrementally, it tells me "Error Code: 1364. Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value
" .

Comment: And if I add 0 as default value explicity, it will tell me "Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
" after second try.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.  Without that, we are guessing.