# MySQL is not incrementing the primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I'm creating a Sims-like game, and having some trouble with MySQL. I have the following function:

```
snprintf(buffer, QUERY_MAX,
    "INSERT INTO children (CHILD_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, CLEAN, HUNGRY, THIRSTY, DOLLARS, PLAYER_ID) VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', %d, %f, %f, %f, %d, %d);",
    0,
    m_firstName.c_str(),
    m_lastName.c_str(),
    m_age,
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    3,
    0);
if (!conn.executeNonQuery(buffer))
    exit(0);
```

This inserts one record successfully. However, I want to get rid of the `CHILD_ID` part in this script and have it automatically increment.

When I go into MySQL Workbench, `CHILD_ID` has the following info: `INT(11)`, `PK`, `NN`, `UQ`, and `UN`. The table has one foreign key `(PLAYER_ID)`, which points to `PLAYER_ID` in the `PLAYERS` table.

AI is unchecked for `CHILD_ID` , so I check that while thinking my problem is solved. I'm about to apply. This is the script it generates:

```
 ALTER TABLE `mvs`.`children` 
 CHANGE COLUMN `CHILD_ID` `CHILD_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

And then this error message pops up:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. Executing: ALTER TABLE `mvs`.`children`  CHANGE COLUMN
>   `CHILD_ID` `CHILD_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
>
> ERROR 1833: Cannot change column 'CHILD_ID': used in a foreign key
>   constraint 'FK_CHAR_TO_CHILD_ID' of table 'mvs.characteristics' SQL
>   Statement: ALTER TABLE `mvs`.`children`  CHANGE COLUMN `CHILD_ID`
>   `CHILD_ID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

It seems to be referring to my characteristics table, which holds general information of the child_id found in children.

In the characteristics table, it has `CHAR_ID` as `INT(10)`, `PK`, `NN`, `UQ`, `UN`, and `AI`. It has a `FK` of `CHILD_ID INT(10)`, `NN`, `UQ`, and `UN`. The reference table is `children`, column `CHILD_ID`, referenced column: `CHILD_ID`.

Overall, I would like to automatically increment new child records when inserting into `CHILDREN`. Being recently new to MySQL, I'm lost with what this error message is referring to along with a solution. I wonder if it's my lesser understanding of `FK's` and if they're really needed. As of now, I have each table referring back to its parent table. Child has a parent id, characteristics has a child id, etc.

Any tips are helpful, thanks!

Comment: What language is this, C++?

Comment: Why is one int 10 and the other int 11? Why would you ever want to specify the size of an int?

Comment: I don't know your API at all, but in Java if you want to auto increment a column you can either not specify a value for it, or pass null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot change column used in a foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a helpful read nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

try change the datatype into `BIGINT` .You dont need to add the `childID` in your query since you are using `AUTO Increment`. Maybe you can use one increment on your code instead for every insertion.

Comment: I changed INT(11) to BIGINT. However, I get the same issue when I add Auto Increment to CHILD_ID. I get the error message posted above. So, it won't auto increment until this error message is solved somehow. True, I could do it from my program, but  feel this would be the less error prone approach in the long run, and less calls to the server, if I can get it working automatically.

Comment: I have the following tables that have foreign keys pointing to table children, such as characteristics, desires, likes, preferences, and skills. Each has a child_id along with a foreign key that points to child_id in children. Because of these foreign keys, I am getting this error message. For instance, if I remove the foreign key from table characteristics, it's going to say table preferences in the error message above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the solution or not, but I got rid of the foreign keys pointing to children.child_id. Next, I added auto increment to children.child_id. This worked finally. Maybe I'm misunderstanding when to use foreign keys.

Comment: oh i see, thanks for your additional information too.