# change autoincrement property in a FK referenced column

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have a foreign key which references another table's autoincrement primary key. In MySQL 5.5 I am able to set the autoincrement to false, but in MySQL 5.7 a Foreign Key Constraint violation arises.

How can I change this settings so I'm allowed to modify the autoincrement property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot change column used in a foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: solutions proposed in that topic drop/recreate the foreign key, which is not a valid solution for my case as we're using liquibase in two different MySQL versions. It already passed in some, but can manage to pass in the other. I would like to know how to disable this check in the DB engine if possible. Anyways, thanks for the reference

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152384/8398549) answer that has more upvotes than the accepted one