# Changing hibernate generator value from increment to native

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, mariadb

**Problem**:
Im expanding a 1 server, 1 db setup to a 2 server 1 db setup. I Run Spring boot and hibernate as the ORM. Every table is currently annotated with:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "id")
```

And an example of the ddl could go something like this:

```
create table drugs

(id                 bigint               not null
    primary key, ....)
```

This gives flushing error when running 2 servers, as each app-server will only check the current index on initialization and then blindly increment the id.

**My current approach:**
To avoid this I want the DB to set the keys and hibernate to implement "native" - strategy and therefor add an AUTO INCREMENT to all-ready existing PRIMARY KEYS.

The problems is that for every table there are multiple foreign key constraints. So I tried [To add Auto increment while running SET FOREIGN KEY CHECK = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint)

```
LOCK TABLES
drugs WRITE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER table drugs DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE drugs MODIFY id bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
UNLOCK TABLES ;
```

But get the error

(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I am open for other ideas to solve this problem or ways to fix my problem :)

Comment: first what is database version ? because if you could use sequence with mariadb 10.3  dialect, it would be better to use a different solution than native

Comment: What would the "native" PK be?  Do you have other tables with `FOREIGN KEYs` into this table?  Vice versa?

Comment: I use MariaDB v. 10.2. I have many tables i need to do the same procedure on, and lots of them have foreign key constraints. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. I ended up with a 5 step procedure:

1. Save every foreign key constraint for a given primary key
2. Remove the above constraints
3. Remove primary key
4. Apply primary key and auto_increment
5. Apply every foreign key again

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE alter_primary_key(P_SCHEMA VARCHAR(64), P_TABLE VARCHAR(64), P_COLUMN VARCHAR(64)) MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE V_CONSTRAINT_NAME VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE V_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE V_REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE V_REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE V_REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM foreign_keys;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE magi.foreign_keys (CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA VARCHAR(64), TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(64), CONSTRAINT_NAME VARCHAR(64), COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(64), REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(64), REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(64), REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(64));
    INSERT INTO magi.foreign_keys (CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME)
    SELECT CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = P_SCHEMA AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = P_COLUMN;


    OPEN C;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH C INTO V_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, V_TABLE_NAME, V_CONSTRAINT_NAME, V_COLUMN_NAME, V_REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, V_REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, V_REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            SET @STMT = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', V_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, '.', V_TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', V_CONSTRAINT_NAME);
            PREPARE STMT FROM @STMT;
            EXECUTE STMT;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    CLOSE C;


    SET @STMT = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' , P_SCHEMA , '.' , P_TABLE , ' DROP PRIMARY KEY');
    PREPARE STMT FROM @STMT;
    EXECUTE STMT;

#     SET @STMT = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' , P_SCHEMA , '.' , P_TABLE , ' MODIFY COLUMN ' , P_COLUMN , ' bigint AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY');
    SET @STMT = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' , P_SCHEMA , '.' , P_TABLE , ' MODIFY COLUMN ', P_COLUMN ,' bigint AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY');
    PREPARE STMT FROM @STMT;
    EXECUTE STMT;


    OPEN C;
        BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        read_loop2: LOOP
            FETCH C INTO V_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, V_TABLE_NAME, V_CONSTRAINT_NAME, V_COLUMN_NAME, V_REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, V_REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, V_REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop2;
            END IF;
            SET @STMT = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',V_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,'.',V_TABLE_NAME,' ADD CONSTRAINT ',V_CONSTRAINT_NAME,' FOREIGN KEY (',V_COLUMN_NAME,') REFERENCES ' , V_REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA , '.' , V_REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,' (',V_REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,')');
            PREPARE STMT FROM @STMT;
            EXECUTE STMT;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    CLOSE C;

END

CALL alter_primary_key('mydatabase', 'mytable', 'id');
```