# Laravel change `id` to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `persons` table and `blogs` table. 
I want to change the `id` column of `persons` table to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

But it throws an error.

**Persons table**

```
id - integer (not auto_increment)
name - string
```

**blogs table**

```
id - integer (auto_increment)
title - string
description - text
created_by - integer (foreign key)
```

I created a migration to change `id` of `persons` table.

**alter user migration**

```
Schema::table('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->change();
        });
```

I throws an Error

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'blogs_created_by_foreign' of table 'db.blogs' (SQL: ALTER TABLE persons CHANGE id id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL)
```

When I try this way.

```
    public function up()
    {
        \DB::statement("LOCK TABLES  blogs WRITE, persons WRITE;");
        \DB::statement("ALTER TABLE blogs DROP FOREIGN KEY created_by, MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED;");
        \DB::statement("ALTER TABLE persons MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;");
        \DB::statement("ALTER TABLE blogs ADD CONSTRAINT created_by FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES persons (id); UNLOCK TABLES;");

    }
```

Error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: LOCK TABLES  blogs WRITE, persons WRITE;)
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot change column used in a foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: I throws an error.
I update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disble foreign key checking then enable it

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
        Schema::table('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->change();
        });
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Comment: I want to change the `id` column to increment, but the problem is `foreign key constraint` in `blogs` table

Comment: I changed the `bigIncrements` to `increments` and it works. Thanks Bro.