# EF Core 6 - How to add AUTO_INCREMENT to a column used by other foreign keys

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a EF Core Code-First table like:

```
public class Entity
{
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And many other tables with:

```
public class Others 
{
    ...
    public byte EntityID { get; set; }
    ...
    [ForeignKey("EntityID")]
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

I just know that EF Core 6 will not set `AUTO_INCREMENT` if you use `byte` as the primary key, so I'm trying to add it with:

```
public class Entity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public byte ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The migration cs is:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<byte>(
                name: "ID",
                table: "Entity",
                type: "tinyint unsigned",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(byte),
                oldType: "tinyint unsigned")
                .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
```

But when I try to migrate, I get this error:

> MySqlConnector.MySqlException: Cannot change column 'ID': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_Others_Entity_EntityID' of table 'Others'

I just want to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` so the foreign keys should be safe. How can I add it, or is there a way for EF Core 6 migration to turn off foreign key checks only during this migration?

Comment: How can you set byte as primary key. The byte have limited value to store like 1 and 0. Use int or Varachar(limit) for that.

Comment: `byte` is `tinyint` in mysql, has values from 0 to 255, which is enough in some cases and can save space.

Comment: For foreign key check you can use Sql function of migrationBuilder.
`migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE Entity NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL")`

Comment: If you are worried about saving space, then set a max length on your strings. I would really recommend switching to a numeric datatype on your models. The current solution, while technically feasible, adds unnecessary difficulty and complexity.

Comment: I actually set a max length on the strings, just emiiting in the question because it's not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@Kiran Joshi`'s comment I can use raw SQL to pause foreign key check and the MySQL version is:

`migrationBuilder.Sql("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");`

Put this and `migrationBuilder.Sql("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1");` (maybe not required) in `Up` and `Down` does the work.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to remove the foreign key constraint, modify the column, and then re-add the foreign key constraint. This method is described in detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13606801).

Is this column the primary key of the table? Does it allow null values?

My recommendation is that you consider performing this change outside of an EF migration, even if you update your migrations to implement the change on future clean DB deployments. Dropping constraints to manipulate the schema can have drastic unintended consequences. Backups are your friend.

Comment: There are too many related foreign key constraints. Is there a way to do that for like 30 foreign keys easily?

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai - The easiest solution here may be to delete your database and your existing migrations and start your schema fresh. After removing all of your migrations, add one migration that will create your table with the desired column specs.

Comment: Delete a database is not always something easy to do, even with some backup/restore mechanism.

Comment: If the system isn't already in production, restarting your schema migrations from scratch may be the best approach. It will be difficult for you to have repeatable migrations in your current state.